# Access violation error when executing TDataSet's Next method

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, tdataset

When looking to move the pointer on to the next record, an error message is shown that says:

> Access violation at address 004070E2 in module 'main_p.exe'. Write of
>   address 00000000

Any way of resolving this?

```
var
  i: integer;
begin
  with dmData.dmEventInfo do
  begin
    tblEventinfo.Open;
    i := 0;
    while NOT tblEventinfo.Eof do
    begin
      arrNames[i] := tblEventinfo['bandname'];
      tblEventinfo.Next;
      i := i + 1;
    end;

  end;
end;
```

Comment: don't use the with statement, it will cause a lot of errors

Comment: Could you tell what the code is doing, and what types the several classes involved are? And get rid of `with`, it can cause a lot of confusion and it may not do what you want it to do.

Comment: Why don't you use `RecordCount`?

Comment: Also what is `tblEventinfo['bandname']`? I think `tblEventinfo` is a table ,No?

Comment: Turn on range checking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't show the declaration of the `arrNames` array , but I think the problem was in the `Length`.

```
var
  i: integer;  arrNames : array of string;
begin
    SetLength(arrNames , tblEventinfo.RecordCount);
    i := 0;
    while NOT tblEventinfo.Eof do
    begin
      arrNames[i] := tblEventinfobandname.Value;
      tblEventinfo.Next;
      Inc(I);
    end;

  end;
```